GraphQLResolver with spring boot 3
I am migrating spring boot version from 2.6.6 to 3.3.0 and jdk 17 to 21
i followed step here :
Springboot 3 and GraphQL compatibility
But now all of my *Resolver.java are not call during a graphql request
So i can't get complexe field with graphql request
How to enable GraphQLResolver in spring boot 3 ?
Product.graphqls :
type Product {
  id: ID
  code: String
  test: Boolean
}

type Query {
  product(code: String): Product
}

type Mutation {
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

ProductQuery.java :
@Controller
@Transactional
public class ProductQuery {
    @QueryMapping
    public ProductDTO product(@Argument String code) {
        if (code != null && !code.isEmpty()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setCode(code);
            return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

ProductResolver.java
@Component
public class ProductResolver implements GraphQLResolver<ProductDTO> {
    public boolean test() {
        return true;
    }
}

and i play this in postman :
query Product($code: String) {
    product(code: $code) {
        code
        test
    }
  }

with
{
    "code": "9862351"
}



I found how to do it,
@Component
public class ProductResolver implements GraphQLResolver<ProductDTO> {
    public boolean test() {
        return true;
    }
}

become
@Controller
public class ProductResolver {
    
    @SchemaMapping(typeName="Product", field="test")
    public boolean test() {
        return true;
    }
}

And Product.java need to have the notation @Entity

You need to update your code so that it no longer references the jdk11 interfaces graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver and GraphQLMutationResolver. Replace with the jdk17 annotations @QueryMapping and @MutationMapping.

I did that and that doesn't work, i will post a part of my code for more details

GraphQLResolver is no more supported in Spring 3.x
Just need to add @SchemaMapping in Controller class
@SchemaMapping(typeName="Product", field="test")
public boolean test() {
    return true;
}

